# Interactive Javascript gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby, macos, rubygems, irb

I've found some online interactive Javascript editors, but I wonder if there is a local equivalent as a gem that lets me test Javascript just like IRB and Rails console in Mac?

Comment: do you mean a JS Shell?  Like http://www.squarefree.com/shell/shell.html

Comment: Doesn't Firebug's, Safari's or Chrome's console suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

- [red](http://github.com/jessesielaff/red)
- [johnson](http://github.com/jbarnette/johnson)
- [therubyracer](http://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer)

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla provides [Rhino shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell).  Please note that it is based on an open source version of JavaScript built on Java.

**Edit:**

Since you are on a mac, you can use jsc which should be installed in: `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc`.

Found this little gem of info on this [page](http://www.metaskills.net/2010/7/9/interactive-javascript-console-with-textmate).

Comment: nice find! seems like exactly what the OP wants

Comment: The problem is that I dont use TextMate=) But nice link though +1

Comment: @ajsie: Yep, see [Stack Overflow Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Comment: @ajsie you don't need to use textmate. Just run it in the terminal as you would run irb.

Answer (score 0):

Since Marcel Korpel has mentioned it as comment and might miss (I missed it first), entering it in here.

Fire up the console in Chrome/Firefox/Safari (Right click on the browser and say Inspect Element and look for Console tab) and start entering the commands that you wanna evaluate.

If you want to type multiple lines without each line being evaluated (like defining object/function), press SHIFT+Enter to go to next line (works in Chrome, have't checked in others)